# Shredding an SSD (or: Is an SSD harder than a CD?)

Tags: ssd, wipe, physical-security

I have a small office shredder which can destroy not only paper but also CDs and credit cards.

[image: paper shredder]

Can I use that to destroy an M2 SSD or will that break my shredder? In other words, are components of an M2 SSD "harder" or "softer" than a CD?

Comment: Hmm... how can a question about physically destroying an SSD be a duplicate of a question about physically destroying hard drive platters?

Comment: Hammers are cheap and easy to use. Spend $10 or less for a 2.5 pound hammer from Harbor Freight (or a similar place) and you are done. Or invest in your health by getting a barbel and use that to smash it. A shredder will most likely be destroyed by this effort if not somewhat hobbled afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, metal is harder than plastic & PCBs are pretty tough too…
It will probably just jam & stop rather than break it if you try it, but it might reduce the life-span of the cutting blades.

I'd go for the large hammer method instead. Hammers are much harder to damage.

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Comment: Most of the components are recyclable… but not if you burn it.

Comment: Hammers work well for this. Shredders are for small thin items. So maybe SDHC cards would shred well? But they could also be cut by a decent pair of basic scissors and such.